# inApp Purchase manager in cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm trying t follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) to implement inApp Purchase in my game with cocos2d.

But when I try to show the products in my scene, get this error:

```
Parse issue, expected expression
```

in this line:

```
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^BOOL sucess, NSArray *products2] {
```

this is my code inside the scene:

```
NSArray *products = nil;
 [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^BOOL sucess, NSArray *products2] {
 if (sucess) {
 products = products2;
 for (int i == 1; i<=products; products.count) {
 SKProduct *product = (SKProduct *) products[i];
 CCLabelTTF *productlabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", product.localizedTitle] fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
 productlabel.position = ccp(200/i,200);
 }

 }

 }];
```

This is my RageIAPHelper.m:

```
@implementation RageIAPHelper

+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                      @"com.razeware.inapprage.drummerrage",
                                      @"com.razeware.inapprage.itunesconnectrage",
                                      @"com.razeware.inapprage.nightlyrage",
                                      @"com.razeware.inapprage.studylikeaboss",
                                      @"com.razeware.inapprage.updogsadness",
                                      nil];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *products = nil;
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL sucess, NSArray *products2) {
 if (sucess) {
   products = products2;
   for (int i == 0; i < products.count; i++) {
     SKProduct *product = (SKProduct *) products[i];
     CCLabelTTF *productlabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", product.localizedTitle] fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
     productlabel.position = ccp(200/i,200);
   }
 }
}];
```

Comment: could you explain what has changed and why?

Comment: The block syntax was incorrect, it just wouldn't compile. Also for-loop initialization was changed because you can't start iterating array from index 1 to index array.count+1, it will cause a crash, your starting point in most cases is 0.

Comment: you should add this to your question otherwise key points will be missed

Comment: @LearnCocos2D sorry? I didn't really ask questions.